# Repair A Pearl Export Series Snare Strainer

Tags: repair, snare-drum

I am struggling with a Pearl snare strainer (identical to the one mentioned in a question asked in Aug 2006! And that is how I got here). Someone handed me down the drum kit and there were not one but two screws stuck in the strainer. What bugs me is that, if I put the two screws back to back, they look exactly like the one long screw I am apparently supposed to use to connect the two parts of the strainer. But I can't make sense of that. I can't imagine that they were glued together or anything like that!!! So my guess is that I somehow have to buy a screw...? But where? I didn't have much success researching online, except for this providential site! I tried to take as many pictures as possible (with the screws in and without) to explain things as best as I could.[image]

Comment: Are you saying the short screw (setbolt) won't reach the backplate  it's supposed to screw into? If indeed it is too short, you will have to find another with the same thread, but make sure it's long enough, but not so long that it catches on the side of the drum as the strainer goes up and down. An ironmongers or diy type store may have one, but a call to Pearl may reveal what thread the setscrew is.

Answer (score 1):

Is this the part you meant when you talk about two screws "back to back"?

This picture is from [How do the parts of an '80's Pearl Export snare strainer come together?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/116455/9426)

It sounds as though your part has broken. I don't expect any sort of glue would be strong enough to join the two parts back together again. You may have a metalworking friend who could join the parts. There's no way you'd find a double-ended screw like that at an ironmongers. So if you can't repair the part I think you'll have to approach Pearl for a replacement strainer unit, as it's probably not worth replacing just the threaded part.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Take the screws to a diy or ironmonger, or better still, a place that specialises in nuts bolts and screws. You will find they can match the tread (very important), and supply what you need. You may have to cut overlength setscrews to their correct length, but surely that's a small price to pay. Also, at the same time, use a better, stronger, longer lasting material than what looks like a stick of licorice to connect the strainer to the lever!